# Adding up Random int as it it created

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to get the computer to save it's random outputs then add them.

Example:

```
ran_num = 1 ; ran_total = 1
ran_num = 3 ; ran_total = 4
```

And so on...

This is all in a `while` loop.

So until the `ran_total` reaches a certain number it will continue to add those numbers.

This is the part of the code I'm trying to fix.

```
if player_bet <= Player.total_money_amount:

    import random

    computer_choice = random.randint(1, 5)
    computer_choice_total =+computer_choice # Over Here

    print('Computer choice: ', computer_choice)
    print("Total Amount", computer_choice_total)

    player_yes_or_no = input('Continue? Yes or No')
        if player_yes_or_no == 'Yes':
```

Comment: Could you please explain how it's not working as expected?

Comment: you probably want to avoid importing 'random' in every iteration of this loop ...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely on this line (line 5):

```
computer_choice_total =+computer_choice
```

`=+` isn't a valid Python operator. Instead, use `+=`, like this:

```
computer_choice_total += computer_choice
```

Also, you'll want to make sure your Python code is indented properly, or else it won't run as you intend it to.

Comment: The += does not make a difference. It does not add the random int that was created. That was just there to show what I was trying to do.  I'll make another post clearing things up. Thanks anyway